# Fetch results efficiently from MySQL in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

1) Questions
Question id
Question Content

2) Tags
Tagid
TagContent

3) Tags_Questions
TagId
Question_Id

There exists a many-to-many relationship between questions and tags.

Problem at hand:

For multiple questions(say m), we have to show tags(say n tags with each question) associated with it on a single page (similar to interesting questions on stack overflow homepage).

Solutions we thought of:

1) For every question, JOIN all 3 tables and retrieve tags but this would take m queries and result for every query would further take O(n) time.So total time:O(m*n)

2) Fetch results for all required *Question id*'s and then loop through results.

Is there any other efficient way to fetch results for the same?

Comment: `So total time: O(m*n)` ... not if you have indices setup properly.  And option 2), looping through everything sounds awful.  Just setup the indices and do a double join.

Comment: `GROUP BY` together with `GROUP_CONCAT()` should do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to obtain what you need with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT q.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.content) as all_tags 
FROM tags_question tq LEFT JOIN tags t ON tq.TagId=t.id LEFT JOIN questions q ON tq.Question_Id=q.id 
GROUP BY tq.Question_Id
```